# How to align two buttons side-by-side in a jumbotron

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm quite a beginner at Bootstrap 3.0 and I really can't figure out how to align two buttons in a jumbotrons side-by-side.

I have this code but it just stacks the buttons above one another:

```
<p>
    <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">See more</a>
</p>
<p>
    <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary">
        Martlet: Faces Edition
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: The bootstrap way would be to either use button-group OR mark the two buttons as inline so they do not use the next row.

Comment: just remove the <p> tags

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML `<p>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) by default is a block element which means it will take up the entire width of it's container and the next element will come underneath. Put the buttons inside the same `p` tag to fix this:

```
<p>
    <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">See more</a>
    <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary">
        Martlet: Faces Edition
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it aligned correctly, you can take advantage of the grid layout.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
        <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">See more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
        <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary">
            Martlet: Faces Edition
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will allow the 2 buttons to sit side by side. Then stack on top of each other in mobile/tablet view. Mind you what @DavidG proposes will work too! Give yourself time, Bootstrap is really easy to get a grasp on!